# Getting error in numpy.fromstring

Tags: numpy

I'm trying to convert this string 'w' having whitespaces without changing the meaning of the original string 'w'.

```
import numpy as np
w="\x01\x02 \x01\x02"
results = np.fromstring(w, dtype=np.int16)
print results
```

I am getting the error message as :

```
> File "prj1.py", line 7, in <module> 
> results = np.fromstring(w, dtype=np.int16)
> ValueError: string size must be a multiple of element size
```

Is there any way to the correct conversion?

Comment: `np.fromstring` in binary mode does not accept separators.  `w` without the space will work.  With `np.int16` it tries to read successive 2 byte blocks as the number.  With the space you have 5 bytes.

Comment: @hpaulj- Thankyou. But is there any way to carry out the conversion of this string to np.int16?

Comment: Remove the spaces?  That should be easy to do with string methods.

Comment: @hpaulj- Yes it worked!! Thankyou :)